# Why am I getting an "End of Statement" compile error in my Excel VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

Below is my code in VBA:

```
Sub Hamza_Starting_to_Learn()

Dim Hamza_Variable As Long

Hamza_Variable = 7

If Hamza_Variable = 7 Then

MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bomb"

Elself Hamza_Variable > 7 Then

MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bigger bomb"

Else

MsgBox Hamza_Variable & "We got ourselves a problem here bro"

End If
```

It is continuously giving the compile error "End of Statement" on the following line:

```
Elself Hamza_Variable > 7 Then
```

It highlights `Then` and gives this error.

Comment: you are missing 1 x `End If` at the end of your code

Comment: Should there be 2 x End If ? I have already put one at the end

Comment: You need 2 x `End If`, one for the first `If Hamza_Variable = 7 Then` and a second because at the end you have another `Else` and not `ElseIf`, try adding a second one and see if it runs

Comment: I've tried adding it after the If Hamza_Variable = 7 Then and also at the end after the first End If. Still doesn't work

Comment: Did you mean `ElseIf` instead of `Elself`? (Note that you spelled the latter with an `l` instead of an `I`.)

Comment: Oh God this was so stupid of me. Its Else-If.. with an I. I was writing Elself with an L, and going crazy over this for the past 3 hours. Thank you so so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Hamza_Starting_to_Learn()

    Dim Hamza_Variable As Long

        Hamza_Variable = 7

    If (Hamza_Variable = 7) Then

        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bomb"

    ElseIf Hamza_Variable > 7 Then

        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bigger bomb"

    Else

        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & "We got ourselves a problem here bro"

    End If

End Sub
```

You didn't end your sub routine with `End Sub`

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention. I am ending with an End Sub. Still gives the same error

Comment: Paste the above code into excel. It works. I think you had a typo in the 'ElseIf'

Comment: Yes it was a typo, i just realized the stupid mistake which had me scratching my head since the last 3 hours. Thank you so much

Comment: How do I do that. Can't find the button

Comment: @HamzaKhalid I posted my comment as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44394076/3775798), since you indicated that this was what resolved your issue. You may accept it by clicking the checkmark icon next to it once you are able to. Glad I could help!

Comment: Done. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting to learn, maybe you should get familair with `Select Case` statement:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Hamza_Starting_to_Learn()

Dim Hamza_Variable As Long

Hamza_Variable = 7

Select Case Hamza_Variable
    Case 7
        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bomb"
    Case Is > 7
        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & " Is da bigger bomb"
    Case Else
        MsgBox Hamza_Variable & "We got ourselves a problem here bro"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I had no idea about this. Will try it out and watch some tutorials on this too. thanks : )

Comment: @HamzaKhalid did you try it ?

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, you wrote `Elself` instead of `ElseIf` (note the typo confusing `l` and `I`) in the line where you are getting your error. This likely confused VBA, which in turn gave you that misleading error message.

<sub>*(Don't feel too bad. [Other people have also had problems distinguishing these two letters in some monospace fonts before.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76837/code-font-doesnt-distinguish-1-and-l))*</sub>